# Dataframe sorting by multiple columns with cumulative sum in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, sorting, group-by, conditional-statements

```
data = {
'Name': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B',' A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
'Level': [5,4,5,4,3,2,3,2,6,7,6,7,1,2,3,4],
'Cost': [10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,5,14,20,25]
}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

With above dataframe, I perform a basic sorting by "Cost" in ascending order

`df.sort_values(by=["Cost"])`

Next, I need to carry out sorting based on below condition while keeping df sorted by "Cost" in ascending order

Condition:

"Level" for each category in "Name" should be in ascending order

I have tried the below code but not really working:

`df.sort_values(by=["Cost", "Name", "Level"], inplace=True)`

I have also thought of sorting after groupby but I cant really get the desired results

My desired outcome:

```
    Name   Level   Cost
    C      1       5
    C      2       14
    A      2       15
    A      3       14
    A      4       11
    A      5       10
    B      2       17
    B      3       16
    B      4       13
    B      5       12
    A      6       18
    A      7       19
    B      6       20
    C      3       20
    B      7       21
    C      4       25
```

To summarize:

In general, df should be sorted by "Cost" in ascending order.

However, for each category ("Name"), "Level" must be in ascending order even though "Cost" is lower.

Note that the actual dataframe is much larger and consists of multiple category.
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Munchkit! Welcome to StackOverflow!

I just spent the past ten minutes trying to understand your proposed sorting idea, with no success

Comment: it sounds like you want to sort by cost ascending, and then within each block of consecutive rows with the same Name, sort by Level

Comment: however, when I sort by Cost ascending, the Name column is ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', ' A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B']

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for your response. You understand the idea correctly. In general it should be a dataframe sorted by cost ascending. It just have a harsh constrain that for groups with same "Name", "Level" must always be sequential in ascending order; and this is the part hindering my sorting process.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you want to sort by groups of consecutively ascending/descending values, for this you need to sort twice, once to  have values in order, then compute the ascending/descending order, then sort again:

```
out = (df
   .sort_values(by=['Name', 'Level'])
   .assign(diff=lambda d: d.groupby('Name')['Cost']
                           .transform(lambda s: s.diff().bfill().ge(0)),
           key=lambda d: d['Cost'].mask(d['diff'], -d['Cost'])
          )
   .sort_values(by=['diff', 'Name', 'key'], ascending=[True, True, False])
   #.drop(columns=['diff', 'key'])
)
```

Output (with intermediates):

```
   Name  Level  Cost   diff  key
5     A      2    15  False   15
4     A      3    14  False   14
1     A      4    11  False   11
0     A      5    10  False   10
7     B      2    17  False   17
6     B      3    16  False   16
3     B      4    13  False   13
2     B      5    12  False   12
8     A      6    18   True  -18
9     A      7    19   True  -19
10    B      6    20   True  -20
11    B      7    21   True  -21
```

##### updated question

I now looks like you want to sort by increasing Cost, but considering the cumulated max cost when data is sorted by Level:

```
out = (df
   .sort_values(by=['Name', 'Level', 'Cost'])
   .assign(key=lambda d: d.groupby('Name')['Cost'].cummax())
   .sort_values('key', kind='stable')
   #.drop(columns='key')
)
```

Output:

```
   Name  Level  Cost  key
12    C      1     5    5
13    C      2    14   14
5     A      2    15   15
4     A      3    14   15
1     A      4    11   15
0     A      5    10   15
7     B      2    17   17
6     B      3    16   17
3     B      4    13   17
2     B      5    12   17
8     A      6    18   18
9     A      7    19   19
10    B      6    20   20
14    C      3    20   20
11    B      7    21   21
15    C      4    25   25
```

Comment: Thanks mozway. I grind through the code and understand the concept. It's a brillant approach. However, when I apply the code to my larger dataframe, it turns out sorted by "Name" primiarily instead of "Cost". I have modified my example to include more data for better explanation of my logic and desired outcome. Would you mind having a look when you are free? Thanks.

Comment: @Munchkit I don't get why C 1/2/3/4 are not grouped together as the values are increasing 5/14/20/25. In other words, why are 5/14 grouped but not 14/20?

Comment: Ultimately the dataframe should sort by "Cost" - ascending. The logic is like this: 1st row takes the lowest cost item (Name: C, Level: 1, Cost: 5), 
However, from 2nd row, since (Name:A, Level:2) has not completed yet, (Name:A, Level:5, Cost:10) is considered impossible and excluded.
As such, next possible 2nd row takes (Name:C, Level:2, Cost:14).
3rd row takes back 3rd possible lowest cost item (Name:A, Level:2, Cost:15).
Starting from 3rd row, it takes back (Name:A, Level:3, Cost:14) since it is now the possible lowest cost item (A - Level 2 has completed).

Comment: OK, I get it, see update. Maybe edit the question to keep both the original and updated question

Comment: Thanks. cummax is exactly the function I am looking for. One more follow up question: Is kind='stable' in sort_values used for maintaining original sequence when multiple keys are in same values?

Comment: Yes it is. Because "key" has duplicates we want to be stable.